# Get enum values but as a dynamic

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the next code :

```dart
enum TestOption1{
  test1("1"),
  test2("10"),
  test3("100");

  final String text;

  const TestOption1(
    this.text,
  );
}

enum TestOption2{
  test1("2"),
  test2("20"),
  test3("200"),
  test3("2000"),
  test3("20000"),
  test3("200000");

  final String text;

  const TestOption2(
    this.text,
  );
}

void main() {

  const enumType = TestOption2;

  if (enumType case (const (TestOption1) || const (TestOption2))) {
    print("enter here");
    optionsList = getOptionsList(enumType, ["2","200"]);
  }

  print(optionsList);
}

List<String> getOptionsList(dynamic option, List<String> testList) {
  try {
    var x = option.values; // Error here

    // (Normally it works like)
    // var x = TestOption1.values

    //    optionsList = optionsList
    //      .map((optionBinary) => x.values // error here
    //         .firstWhere(
    //            (test) => true,
    //          )
    //          .name)
    //      .toList();

    return [];
  } catch (e) {
    return [];
  }
}
```

In this case i try to do this functions to minimize as possible but i don't find a way to solve it or at least if it exists another way to minimize the code.